# Communication between Desktop Java & Web Application eg. PHP

Tags: java, php, web-applications, desktop-application

How do I connect my Java Desktop application with a PHP Web Application. Any example codes and technologies I should know of? I just want a simple implementation (its a school project and I don't have much time to perfect it)

On the web side, perhaps I can have a REST-ful API. But what about the Java Desktop side (I'm more of a web developer). How can I pull & pull data from my Java app?

Comment: I have the same issue? what did you use for this purpose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create an http-endpoint in the desktop app as well. For instance you can embed a simple servlet container like [jetty](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Tutorial/Embedding_Jetty).

Once you have a servlet container, you can use something like [Jersey](http://jersey.java.net/) to write a REST API (or you can just use the Servlet API).

Another option is to create a [ServerSocket](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/clientServer.html) in the java app, and connect to it from the [php app](http://snipplr.com/view/1677/).

There is also a [php-java](http://php-java-bridge.sourceforge.net/pjb/) bridge, if you want to get really fancy ;)